# GIT desasociado visual studio 2022

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022, git-merge

Tengo un problema con visual studio, cada vez que intento hacer un pull en git, no me permite hacer merges, desconozco si haya que configurar algo en el repositorio o simplemente es tema de visual studio, ésto pasa cuando se hace un pull request después de hacer un commit y si hay conflictos en el código (que yo y algún compañero trabajemos en el mismo documento), adjunto pruebas (las rutas y el ID del branch se enecuentran censurados, igualmente marca fusión mediante cambios pero no me da opción a merge):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]